# where storing the data on Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using the laravel, when I'm looking the database the data on sql file and the site interface is different, I'm wondering that where the data storing and how I can reset that. I want to use laravel scheduler for re-calculating the some data's every 24 hrs.

[the mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu4E3.jpg)
[site interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTLTk.png)

Comment: Please make sure you are checking the correct database used by your application

Comment: @gguney how? database configuration is only setting up in .env file right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your env file in your directory. There should be parameters of your database so you can use these parameters for connecting the database that you used by your application.

For scheduler you should use laravel's task scheduler. It is quite simple to run cron jobs in laravel.

Comment: .env file is ok and the database successfully connected. what's the command for scheduler?